# Map values from parent class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, mapping

```
public class ChildItemDTO: ParentItemDTO
    { ...

       public static ChildItemDTO Map(ChildItem model)
       {
           if (model == null) return null;
           var retModel = ParentItemDTO.Map(model) as ChildItemDTO ;

           if (retModel != null)
           {
               ...
           }
           return retModel;
       }
    }
```

Well, I have parent and child classes. I want to map Model values to DTO.
In order to write less code I want to use Mapper from Parent class.

`ParentItemDTO.Map(model)` this line returns object of type `ParentItemDTO`

Problem - how can I cast Parent class to Child class? Firstly I thought it will be work while I understood that only opposite way works (from Child to Parent)

Comment: Why not use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)?

Comment: Why not use interface `IItemDTO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse the parent class mapping you could alter/overload the mapping to pass in an instance to map to:

```
       var retModel = new ChildItemDTO();
       ParentItemDTO.Map(model, retModel);
       // map child-specific fields here
```

AutoMapper has similar functionality that lets you pass in an instance to populate as well as returning a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly cast a Parent to a Child. C# Inheritance does not work that way. The choice you have is to create a new Child object with the Parent properties

```
   var parentModel = ParentItemDTO.Map(model);
   var retModel = new ChildItemDTO 
                  {
                    Name= parentModel.Name,
                    Age= parentModel.Age,
                  };
```